# Obfuscated C recursion Code Please explain

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to learn recusrion from a book, but there's something that's not being explained clearly enough for me.

The following code

```
int f(int n, int x, int y)
{
if(n==0) return x+y;
if(y==0) retun x;
return f(n-1,f(n,x,y-1),f(n,x,y-1)+y);
}
```

what happen if i call f(1,2,2);

any help with explain and thanks

Comment: Use a debugger and step though it, while making notes of the call-stack on paper.

Comment: syntax error line 4 `retun`

Comment: Or rather add printing statements and analyze the trace.

Comment: Why would you be learning from a book that uses obfuscated code examples?

Comment: @Cody Gray yes it obfuscated code examples

Comment: Yes, either step through it with the debugger, or add print statements, or follow it with pencil and paper.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth  can you help with good debugger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoreticaly and doing it in paper:

f(1,2,2)->return f(1-1,f(1,2,2-1),f(1,2,2-1)+2) Then we do the internal

Both are the same f(1,2,2-1) -> return f(0,f(1,2,1-1),f(1,2,1-1)+1) again the internal

Again both are the same -> return 2 (x=2); so we go back

return f(0, f(1,2,1-1) -> 2, f(1,2,1-1) ->2+1) -> f(0, 2, 3) -> return 2+3(x+y);

Again back f(0, f(1,2,2-1) -> 5, f(1,2,2-1) ->5+2) -> return 5+7(x+y) -> The answer is 12;

Answer (score 4):

```
int f(int n, int x, int y)
{
  int result;

  if(n==0) {
    printf("f(%d, %d, %d) -> %d\n", n, x, y, x+y);
    return x+y;
  }
  if(y==0) {
    printf("f(%d, %d, %d) -> %d\n", n, x, y, x);
    return x;
  }

  printf("recursing for f(%d, %d, %d)...\n", n, x, y);
  result = f(n-1,f(n,x,y-1),f(n,x,y-1)+y);
  printf("f(%d, %d, %d) -> %d\n", n, x, y, result);
  return result;
}
```

Your code is not obfuscated. Were you referring to something you did not post?

Comment: -1 for no comment saying what it does.

Comment: @user2151446 you're right, I didn't give him a fish. Instead, I showed him how to fish.

Answer (score 1):

On each call, n is decremented. So if n is positive on the first call, the function will be called again n times internally, and then exit.

Overall the function does arithmetic operations on x and y a finite number of times.

If you're trying to learn recursion, factorial() is simpler to understand how useful recursion can be.

```
int factorial(int number) 
{
    int temp;

    if(number <= 1) return 1;

    temp = number * factorial(number - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

**Call trace**

factorial(3)    = 3 * factorial(2)
                = 3 * ( 2 * factorial(1) )
                = 3 * ( 2 * ( 1 * factorial(0) ))
                = 3 * ( 2 * ( 1 *      1     ) ))
                = 6

**Simple overview of recursion:**

"As a simple rule of recursion, any function can be computed using a recursive routine if :
1. The function can be expressed in its own form.
2. There exists a termination step, the point at which f(x) is known for a particular ‘x’.

Therefore to write a recursive program for the factorial of any number, we have to express the factorial function in a recursive form using the above 2 rules :
1. fact(n) = fact(n-1)*n (recursive definition of factorial).
2. if n=1, return 1 (termination step)"

Comment: Maybe they don't use factorial as an example because recursion is a terrible way to calculate it. I have seen pascals triangle used as an example too, which is even worse. However +1 for good explanation.